# Android: SQLite encryption without external libraries

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption, compilation, java-native-interface

I am looking for a solution to perform **encryption/decryption** of a `SQLite` databse in a Android app **without using** any external libraries etc...

I read a lot about SQLCipher (https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/),

> the SQLite extension that provides transparent 256-bit AES encryption
>   of database files

but it's not what I'm looking for...

Is it possible, for example, to compile the `SQLite` extension of my android project (which is in **C**) including the encryption module (*This one*: https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki from the SQLite org) ?

After I should be able to use it from my *jni folder*.

I actually don't know if it's the correct way or even if it's possible...

If you have any solutions, suggestions...

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

Comment: Humm ok. And do you konw where can I find the SEE-enabled version of SQLite3?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this Nicolas.If so can you please tell me where can I find SEE enabled version of sqlite

Comment: @NishatJahan, actually you can find it on internet, I don't know if it's legal but you can find it. When it's done, you have to build your ndk with it and then, encrypt/decrypt your database like : db.execSQL("PRAGMA key =  'yourKey' ");